# How to show a string on changing drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/118/)
 when any of the check box is selected then the drop down menu will be enabled.There are 4 options text,boolean,option and option1.Now when I select the option drop down then another 3 check boxes are shown good avg and poor but nothing happens when I select options1 or text or boolean. Can any body please tell me how will show yesy or no if boolean is selected or enter some text string when text drop down is selected

This is for option drop down that shows check boxes

```
('#addNew .QSelect').change(function() {
    var cbs = $(this).closest('td').next().children();
    if ($('.show-checkboxes', $(this)).is(':selected')) {
        $(cbs).show();
    } else {
        $(cbs).hide();
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: you mean you want to display "yes" and "no" at somewhere else when the user select boolean from the drop down?

Comment: no no some where.there are 3 columns question,questiontype and 3rd column is not having any heading.I want to show yes or no in the 3rd column when boolean is selected

Comment: @jhyap can you post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code,

```
var option = '<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">Good</label><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">Average</label><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3">Poor</label>';
var txt = 'Enter Some Text';
var bool = 'Yes or No';
$('#addNew .QSelect').change(function () {
    if (this.value == 'op') $(this).closest('tr').find('.out').html(option);
    if (this.value == 'txt') $(this).closest('tr').find('.out').html(txt);
    if (this.value == 'bool') $(this).closest('tr').find('.out').html(bool);
});
```

- Write your `HTML` markup or `text` separately as a javascript `variables` to dynamically change when user select the option.
- Check which option is `selected` using `change` event listener. Then write your `if` condition to show element when user select option from `select`.

<kbd>**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/Wy22s/123/)**</kbd>